# Exhausting Heat in Server Rack

Tags: rack, cooling

I was recently provided a 4 post Server Rack/Cabinet (48U) to fit all my equipment cleanly. One of the items they provided was a Tripp Lite Rackmounted A/C Unit (SRCOOL7KRM). This was truly Awesome thinking on their part, although I wish they had spoken with me before purchasing as I have no way to direct the Exhaust up and out of the little 'Closet' the Rack is located in.

What I am looking for is not exactly 'Low Cost' solutions, but I am not shy when it comes to DIY solutions either. I have a Drop Ceiling in the room with No A/C Ducts nor vents into the room (reason why Management gave me the unit.). I was originally thinking of something simply like using the same type of Ducting that you would find with a Clothing Dryer. That would work to get the hot air through the Ceiling, but the trick is catching the Hot Air and guiding it to that exhaust duct. Anyone have any thoughts? Anyone out there with a SRCOOL7KRM in the same situation as me come up with something?

I Thank you in Advance for any Advice and/or Guidance provided in your Replies.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you figured something out already, but take a look at the SRCOOL7KDUCT. Its meant to duct the heat out the back door and into a drop ceiling like you describe.

https://www.tripplite.com/smartrack-duct-kit-srcool7krm~SRCOOL7KDUCT/

I'd love to hear how you make out. We're still playing around with this device to get it to be effective in a similar situation with just 4 servers in the rack.